# ajaxStart fails on subsequent requests when using getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I'm trying to use the ajaxStart and ajaxStop events with getJson calls to my webserver.  The ajaxStart event is triggered on the first request, but not on subsequent requests.  The encID ensures that each requested url is somewhat unique.  It doesn't work on Firefox 3.5 or IE 7.  In firebug, I can see the the getJSON requests are firing and completing.  Any ideas?

Here are my ajax event bindings.

```
$('#ajaxLoader').ajaxStart(function(){    
   $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Here is my getJSON call.

```
$.getJSON(location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/enc-comment/get?format=json&c=?' + '&encId=' + encId,
function(data){
   // change text of a div
});
```

If I switch the getJSON call with a .ajax GET or POST, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pass one more extra parameter with your URL:

```
?+"randomParam="+(Math.random() * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Yashwant is referring to interrupting automatic browser caching using a random parameter.

A prettier way of doing this is to just use $.ajaxSetup()

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

This will block browser caching for all your ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Add this statement:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options){options.global = true;});
```

Bug Ticket： http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8338

This is because you're doing a JSONP request.